# Right way to cipher / uncipher message with Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, aes

I use this to Cipher a message:

```
const CIPHER_ALGORITHM = 'aes256';

var cipherMessage = function(data, key) {
  try {
    var cipher       = crypto.createCipher(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, key);
    var cipheredData = cipher.update(data, "binary", "hex");
    cipheredData += cipher.final("hex");
    return cipheredData;
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

And this to uncipher a message:

```
var decipherMessage = function(msg, key) {
  var ret = {};

  try {
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(CIPHER_ALGORITHM, key);
    var decipheredMessage = decipher.update(msg, 'hex', 'binary');
    decipheredMessage += decipher.final("binary");
    ret = JSON.parse(decipheredMessage);
  } catch(e) {
    return null;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

I have to call them multiple time (every second), it it the right way to do it ? 
Is there any possibility of memory leak with that ?

Comment: A memory leak? Without leaving any references in containers???

Comment: Closing as too broad, try codereview.stackexchange.com instead. Note that you may want to indicate your use cases and threat models before posting there. Without those, it's just two blocks of code.